# How to convert parse line by line csv files to create one json file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, csv, parsing

Basically, I have 4 csv files that contain students, their ids, their grades, and courses.

Right now I have

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const User = require('./models/user');

fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'users.csv'))
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    // pipe the parsed input into a csv formatter
    .pipe(csv.format({ headers: true }))
    // Using the transform function from the formatting stream
    .transform((row, next) => {
        User.findById(row.id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            return next(null, {
                id: row.id,
                name: row.name,
                email: row.email,
                country: row.country,
                age: row.age,
                totalAverage: row.totalAverage,

            });
        });
    })
    .pipe(process.stdout)
    .on('end', () => process.exit());
```

Using `fast-csv`, this just reads line by line and prints each columns data row by row. I don't know if it's better to store each student in a arraylist and have their data and courses stored inside. And then, write to a json.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good to store them in an Array and we can process them at `.on('end')` handler.